# Как убрать пустую строку Xml C#

Tags: c#, xml

Мне нужно вытянуть RSS данные для работы с [Interfax](http://www.interfax.by/news/feed).
Но проблема это XML. Когда пытаюсь вытянуть, в данном RSS первая строка пустая. И  `XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(url);`Не хочет считывать данные и выкидывает ошибку (Что типа начало файла начинается с 2 строки). Может кто встречался с такой ситуацией и решил её подскажите пожалуйста. Нужно как то убрать эту пустую строку что бы загрузило.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все верно, в этом XML первый символ `\n` что недопустимо и вызывает исключение `System.Xml.XmlException`:

> Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node
>   in the document, and no whitespace characters are allowed to appear
>   before it. Line 2, position 3.

Просто удалите первый символ из строки с XML:

```
const string url = "https://www.interfax.by/news/feed";

string xmlStr;
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    xmlStr = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    xmlStr = xmlStr.Remove(0, 1);
}

var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);
```

Comment: У меня тут проблемка выскочила -> {"Illegal characters in path."} Что вытягивать вытягивает но не могу запихнуть в  XDocument.Load(xmlStr);

Comment: @JMNext проверьте, что загружается по URL. У меня источник через раз отваливается

Comment: кодировка сбивается при вытяжке и че то ридер не определяет её

Answer (score 0):

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        string xmlText;
        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
            xmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Temp/temp")) {
            writer.Write(xmlText.Remove(0, 1));
        }
```

Вот так я сделал. Используя резервный фаил и не потерял кодировки. И при вытяжке просто загрузил его в `xdoc = XDocument.Load(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Temp/temp");`